# Move object to the subset if the key is matched

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

```
[{id:1, name:'Chan', supervisor:''},
{id:2, name:'Wong', supervisor:'1'},
{id:3, name:'Fong', supervisor:'1'},
{id:4, name:'Ho', supervisor:'2'},
]
```

expected result

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Chan",
    supervisor: "",
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Wong",
        supervisor: "1",
        children: [{ id: 4, name: "Ho", supervisor: "2" }]
      },
      { id: 3, name: "Fong", supervisor: "1" }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to achieve this format like the above. Have tried to use lodash map and filter.
Want to know if there any fastest method to do that? Many thanks in advance.

Currently I have tried.

```
let children = [];
const transformedDataRecords = records.map((record) => {

  let user = _.filter(records, { id: record.supervisor });

  if (user.length>0) {
    console.log(user[0].children);
    if(!!(user[0].children)){
      children = user[0].children;
    }
    children.push(record);
    user = { ...user, children };

    console.log(user);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you update the question with what you have tried so far?

Comment: Unless you actually post the solution you came up with, we can't really tell you if there's a faster way. If you don't have a solution yet, tell us what part you're stuck on.

Comment: currently not have a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from

```
const staff = [{id:1, name:'Chan', supervisor:''},
{id:2, name:'Wong', supervisor:'1'},
{id:3, name:'Fong', supervisor:'1'},
{id:4, name:'Ho', supervisor:'2'},
]
```

This is a nice place to use Maps. You can keep a reference to each object by its ID without having to care about its location in the array:

```
const staffById = new Map(
  // key-value pairs
  staff.map(person => [person.id, person])
)

// Create the children arrays
staff.forEach(
  person => {
    if (person.supervisor !== "") {
      // Maps do care about whether data is String or Number so we have to
      // convert the supervisor field to Number to ensure they match.
      const supervisorParsed = Number(person.supervisor)
      const supervisorObj = staffById.get(supervisorParsed)
      // Ensure there is an array to insert into
      supervisorObj.children = supervisorObj.children || []
      supervisorObj.children.push(person)
    }
  }
)

// References updated, now filter out everyone from the top-level array who is not a top-level supervisor.
const output = staff.filter(person => person.supervisor === '')
```

Comment: Also I'm not too familiar with lodash's filter() function, but I suspect you might be running into the same problem, where the match is not working because `"1" !== 1`.

Comment: cannot get the desired solution with your solution.
https://codepen.io/alanko0202/pen/VwmGMbr

Comment: @AlanKo In your pen, replace `console.log(output)` with `console.log(JSON.stringify(output))`; that shows the inner structure of the objects. I was not able to find a problem with the output.